# Which skills provide leadership bonuses for your squad?

Tags: eve-online

In EVE Online, a variety of skills that you train can increase various statistics for any members of your squad while you're in a fleet.

The bonuses I'm talking about are the Leadership bonus, which provides a 2% bonus to fleet targeting speed per level, or Mining Foreman, which increases mining yield by 2% per level.

Which other skills provide bonuses to your fleet?

Do each of these bonuses stack (ie: if you had one member of the fleet that had each skill that provided fleet bonuses, would the fleet get all of those bonuses)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Enhancement bonuses do not stack. Only the highest level member of the fleet will give the respective bonus.

## Basic enhancement skills

### Armored Warfare

```
Requires Leadership (1)
Provides an increase to each affected ship's Armor HP of 2%/level.
```

### Siege Warfare

```
Requires Leadership (1)
Provides an increase to each affected ship's Shield capacity of 2%/level.
```

### Skirmish Warfare

```
Requires Leadership (1)
Provides an increase to each affected ship's Maximum Velocity of 2%/level.
```

### Information Warfare

```
Requires Leadership (1)
Improves each ship's maximum targeting range by 2%/level
```

### Mining Foreman

```
Requires Leadership (1)
Increases each ship's mining yield by 2%/level
```

## Advanced enhancement skills

### Warfare Link Specialist

```
Requires Leadership (5)
adds 10%/level to the effectiveness of gang assist modules
```

### Armored Warfare Specialist

```
Requires Armored Warfare (5)
Increases effectiveness of Armored Warfare link modules by 100%/level
```

### Siege Warfare Specialist

```
Requires Siege Warfare (5)
Increases effectiveness of Siege Warfare link modules by 100%/level
```

### Skirmish Warfare Specialist

```
Requires Skirmish Warfare (5)
Increases effectiveness of Skirmish Warfare link modules by 100%/level
```

### Information Warfare Specialist

```
Requires Information Warfare (5)
Increases effectiveness of Information Warfare link modules by 100%/level
```

### Mining Director

```
Requires Mining Foreman (5)
Increases effectiveness of Mining Foreman link modules by 100%/level
```

[Source](http://www.eve-wiki.net/index.php?title=Leadership_skills_overview)

Answer (score 4):

Only the Skills in the Leadership section have the possibility of affecting pilots in a fleet. There are three types of leadership skills, those that increase your personal ability to command a number of people, those that give bonuses when you are a booster, and those that increase the effectiveness of Warfare Link modules. For any of these skills to matter, the [fleet must be set up properly](http://wiki.eveuniversity.org/Fleet_Leadership#Leadership) or else the 'flow' of bonuses will be impeded.

Command Skills:

*Fleet Command*: As a fleet commander, this skill allows you to pass on bonuses to wing commanders below you, to a maximum of one wing per level of the skill (5 in total).  This skill requires Wing Command trained to 5.
*Wing Command*: As a wing commander, this skill allows you to pass on bonuses to squad commanders below you, to a maximum of one squad per level of the skill (5 in total). This skill requires Leadership trained to 5.
*Leadership*: As a squad commander, this skill allows you to pass on bonuses to squad members below you, to a maximum of two members per level of the skill (10 in total).

Direct Skills:

*Leadership*: Grants a 2% bonus to fleet members' targeting speed per skill level.
*Armored Warfare*: Grants a 2% bonus to fleet members' armor hit points per skill level.
*Information Warfare*: Grants a 2% bonus to fleet members' targeting range per skill level.
*Siege Warfare*: Grants a 2% bonus to fleet members' shield capacity per skill level.
*Skirmish Warfare*: Grants a 2% bonus to fleet members' agility per skill level.
*Mining Foreman*: Grants a 2% bonus to fleet members' mining yield per level.

Warfare Links are high slot modules that can only be fitted to certain classes of ships ( Battlecruisers, Command Ships, T3s with the right subsystem, carriers and titans and the indy ships ).

**Armored Warfare Specialist**
Allows the use of armored warfare links and increases the effectiveness these modules.
*Armored Warfare Link - Damage Control* - reduces the capacitor need of armor repairers and remote armor repairers by 2% per level.
*Armored Warfare Link - Passive Defense* - increases the fleet's armor resistances by 2% per level. This is a very useful module for armor fleets.
*Armored Warfare Link - Rapid Repair* - increases the speed (i.e. reduces the duration) of armor repairers and remote armor repairers by 2% per level.

**Information Warfare Specialist**
Allows the use of information warfare links and increases the effectiveness these modules.
*Information Warfare Link - Electronic Superiority* - increases the strength of electronic warfare modules. For each level, increases ECM jam strength by 2%, sensor dampener targeting range and scan resolution penalty by 1.2%, tracking disruptor optimal and falloff penalty by 1.2%, and target painter signature bonus by 2%.
*Information Warfare Link - Recon Operation* - increases the optimal range of electronic warfare modules by 2% per level.
*Information Warfare Link - Sensor Integrity* - increases the sensor strengths of all ships in the fleet by 3% per level.

**Mining Director**
Allows the use of mining foreman links and increases the effectiveness these modules.
*Mining Foreman Link - Harvester Capacitor Efficiency* - reduces the capacitor need of mining lasers and gas & ice harvesters by 2% per level.
*Mining Foreman Link - Laser Optimization* - reduces the duration of mining lasers and gas & ice harvesters by 2% per level.
*Mining Foreman Link - Mining Laser Field Enhancement* - increases the optimal range of mining lasers and gas & ice harvesters by 4.5% per level.

**Siege Warfare Specialist**
Allows the use of siege warfare links and increases the effectiveness these modules.
*Siege Warfare Link - Active Shielding* - increases the speed (i.e. reduces the duration) of shield boosters and shield transporters by 2% per level.
*Siege Warfare Link - Shield Efficiency* - reduces the capacitor need of shield boosters and shield transporters by 2% per level.
*Siege Warfare Link - Shield Harmonizing* - increases the fleet's shield resistances by 2% per level. As for its armor counterpart, this is a very useful module for shield fleets.

**Skirmish Warfare Specialist**
Allows the use of skirmish warfare links and increases the effectiveness these modules.
*Skirmish Warfare Link - Evasive Maneuvers* - reduces the signature radius of the fleet's ships by 2% per level.
*Skirmish Warfare Link - Interdiction Maneuvers* - increases the optimal range of propulsion jamming modules by 3% per level.
*Skirmish Warfare Link - Rapid Deployment* - increases the speed of afterburner and microwarpdrive modules by 2% per level.

As usual, my information is directly from the [Uniwiki](http://wiki.eveuniversity.com) articles on [Fleet Leadership](http://wiki.eveuniversity.org/Fleet_Leadership) and [Warfare Links](http://wiki.eveuniversity.org/Warfare_links).